# Exchange Rates Display

Tags: javascript, html, css, exchange-server

Why is the exchange rate always displaying N/A in the following code after a currency pair is chosen, and how best to fix it?

I expect the exchange rate value to display the calculated valued when a pair is chosen.

What di I do get it it fixed to display the rates properly?

Is there any library I can use to do a better conversion?

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    <title>Cross-Border Payment App</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    
        form {
            width: 80%;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
    
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #333333;
            cursor: pointer; /* Add cursor style to indicate it's clickable */
        }
    
        h1:hover {
            text-decoration: underline; /* Add underline effect on hover */
        }
    
        label {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    
        input[type="text"],
        select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 3px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    
        input[type="submit"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: #ffffff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        input[type="submit"]:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
    
        .exchange-rate {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-style: italic;
            color: #999999;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    
        select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        email {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    
        .bank-options {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            max-height: 100px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    
        .bank-option {
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    
        .bank-option:hover {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    
        .bank-option.disabled {
            color: #999999;
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }
    </style>    
    
  </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Glocal Payments</h1>
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'glocal' %}" onsubmit="return validatePaymentAmount()">
            {% csrf_token %}
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="sender_name">Sender's Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="sender_name" id="sender_name">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="sender_account_number">Sender's Account Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="sender_account_number" id="sender_account_number">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="sender_country">Sender's Country:</label>
                <select name="sender_country" id="sender_country">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                    <option value="USA">USA</option>
                    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="sender_bank">Sender's Bank:</label>
                <input type="text" name="sender_bank" id="sender_bank">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="recipient_name">Recipient's Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="recipient_name" id="recipient_name">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="recipient_account_number">Recipient's Account Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="recipient_account_number" id="recipient_account_number">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="recipient_country">Recipient's Country:</label>
                <select name="recipient_country" id="recipient_country">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                    <option value="USA">USA</option>
                    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="recipient_bank">Recipient's Bank:</label>
                <input type="text" name="recipient_bank" id="recipient_bank">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="sender_currency">Sender's Currency:</label>
                <select name="sender_currency" id="sender_currency" onchange="calculateExchangeRate()">
                    <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                    <option value="USD-NGN">NGN</option>
                    <option value="NGN-USD">USD</option>
                    <!-- Add other sender currencies here -->
                </select>
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="recipient_currency">Recipient's Currency:</label>
                <select name="recipient_currency" id="recipient_currency" onchange="calculateExchangeRate()">
                    <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                    <option value="NGN-USD">USD</option>
                    <option value="USD-NGN">NGN</option>
                    <!-- Add other recipient currencies here -->
                </select>
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
                <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
            </div>

            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="exchange_rate">Exchange Rate:</label>
                <span id="exchange_rate" class="exchange-rate"></span>
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="narration">Narration/Purpose:</label>
                <input type="text" name="narration" id="narration">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-field">
                <input type="submit" value="Make Payment">
            </div>
        </form>   
        {% block scripts %}  
        <script>
            function calculateExchangeRate() {
    var senderCurrency = document.getElementById("sender_currency").value;
    var recipientCurrency = document.getElementById("recipient_currency").value;

    // Define the exchange rates
    var exchangeRates = {
      "USD-NGN": 770.00,  // Exchange rate from USD to NGN
      "NGN-USD": 1 / 770.00,  // Exchange rate from NGN to USD
      // Add other currency pairs and their respective exchange rates here
    };

    var currencyPair = senderCurrency + "-" + recipientCurrency;
    var exchangeRate = exchangeRates[currencyPair];

    // Display the exchange rate or "N/A"
    var exchangeRateField = document.getElementById("exchange_rate");
    if (exchangeRateField) {
      if (exchangeRate !== undefined) {
        exchangeRateField.textContent = "Exchange Rate: " + exchangeRate.toFixed(4);
      } else {
        exchangeRateField.textContent = "N/A";
      }
    }
  }

  // Call the calculateExchangeRate function initially and on currency selection change
  document.getElementById("sender_currency").addEventListener("change", calculateExchangeRate);
  document.getElementById("recipient_currency").addEventListener("change", calculateExchangeRate);

  calculateExchangeRate(); // Call it initially to display the exchange rate for the selected currency pair
        </script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: SenderCurrency/recipientCurrency appear to already be in the format of a pair.  If you console log currencyPair you will see something like `NGN-USD-USD-NGN`.  Please learn to use the debugging tools of your browser.

Comment: In the console log I see that validatePaymentAmount is undefined. It would be worth stepping through line by line doing a console.log on values too to see exactly what else might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As James mentioned in his comment the options in your currency selectors have the values of `NGN-USD` or `USD-NGN` so *really* you only need one select.

You may also want to coerce the input value string to a number (to mitigate any errors) although, in this case, it's not strictly necessary.

In this reduced example I've called the select "conversion".

```js
// Cache the relevant elements
const conversionEl = document.querySelector('#conversion');
const amountEl = document.querySelector('#amount');
const rateEl = document.querySelector('#exchange_rate');

// Add listeners to the elements
conversionEl.addEventListener('change', calculateExchangeRate);
amountEl.addEventListener('input', calculateExchangeRate);

// Set up the exchange rates
const exchangeRates = {
  'NGN-USD': 1 / 770.00,
  'USD-NGN': 770.00
};

function calculateExchangeRate() {
  
  // Get the values from the elements
  const conversion = conversionEl.value;
  const amount = Number(amountEl.value);

  // Set the text content of the rate span to be the
  // amount multiplied by the conversion value (defined in
  // the exchangeRates object)
  rateEl.textContent = amount * exchangeRates[conversion];
}
```

```css
body,form{padding:20px}email,input[type=text],select{width:100%;padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px}.bank-option:hover,body{background-color:#f2f2f2}body{font-family:Arial,sans-serif}form{width:80%;background-color:#fff;border-radius:4px;box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}h1{text-align:center;color:#333;cursor:pointer}h1:hover{text-decoration:underline}label{font-weight:700}input[type=text],select{border:3px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px}input[type=submit]{width:100%;padding:10px 20px;background-color:#4caf50;color:#fff;border:none;border-radius:4px;cursor:pointer}input[type=submit]:hover{background-color:#45a049}.exchange-rate{font-size:14px;font-style:italic;color:#999;margin-top:5px}email,select{border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px}.bank-options{border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px;max-height:100px;overflow-y:auto;padding:5px}.bank-option{cursor:pointer;padding:5px}.bank-option.disabled{color:#999;cursor:not-allowed}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <label for="conversion">Conversion</label>
  <select name="conversion" id="conversion">
    <option value="">Select Currency</option>
    <option value="USD-NGN">USD-NGN</option>
    <option value="NGN-USD">NGN-USD</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-field">
  <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
  <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
</div>

<div class="form-field">
  <label for="exchange_rate">Exchange Rate:</label>
  <span id="exchange_rate" class="exchange-rate"></span>
</div>
```